# Maximum Likelihood Estimate of a Piecewise pdf

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, maximum-likelihood

> Suppose $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ are i.i.d random variables having pdf
>
> $$ f(x\mid\theta)=   \begin{cases} 
>  \frac{4}{\theta}-\frac{4x}{\theta^2} & \frac{\theta}{2} \lt x \lt
>  \theta \\ \frac{4x}{\theta^2} & 0 \lt x \leq \frac{\theta}{2} \\ 0 &
>  \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$
>
> where $\theta\in(0,\infty)$.
>
> (a) Give a method of moments estimator of $\theta$
>
> (b) For the case of $n= 2$, $x_1= 10$, and $x_2= 4.5$, give the
>   mle of $\theta$.

**My Attempt:**

(a) I have that

$$\mathsf E(X)=\int_0^{\frac{\theta}{2}} \frac{4x^2}{\theta^2}dx+\int_{\frac{\theta}{2}}^{\theta} \frac{4x}{\theta}-\frac{4x^2}{\theta^2}dx=\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Hence

$$\mu_1'=\frac{\theta}{2}\Rightarrow \theta=2\mu_1'\Rightarrow \hat{\theta}_{MME} =  2\bar{x}$$

Is this a valid solution?

(b)

I'm not quite sure how to find the MLE since this is a piecewise function. The usual case I have dealt with is where

$$L(\theta\mid \vec{x})=f(\vec{x}\mid\theta)$$

and you just take the product of the individual densities.

One thing I notice is that since $x_1= 10.0$, and $x_2= 4.5$ it cannot be the case that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are both in $\left(\frac{\theta}{2},\theta\right)$. I also note that the only way $x_1, x_2\in\left(0,\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$ is if $\theta\gt20$. Could I somehow use these facts to get the likelihood on a case-by-case basis where either$$x_1,x_2\in\left(0,\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$ or $$x_2\in\left(0,\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$$ $$x_1\in\left(\frac{\theta}{2},\theta\right)$$

My concern with going this route is that the probability that one of these two events occurs depends on $\theta$

Comment: For $n=2$, isn't the likelihood function of the form $$L(\theta\mid x_1,x_2)=\prod_{i=1}^2\left[\left(\frac{4}{\theta}-\frac{4x_i}{\theta^2}\right)\mathbf1_{\theta/2<x_i<\theta}+\frac{4x_i}{\theta^2}\mathbf1_{0<x_i<\theta/2}\right]\quad?$$

In any case, you would have to study the parameter space given the sample like you are already doing to find the MLE.

Comment: @StubbornAtom That likelihood function makes sense to me. I guess it's the next step I'm stuck on.

Comment: The MLE here requires careful analysis. Yours is a specific case of the triangular distribution mentioned [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/64102/mle-for-triangle-distribution). Also see the paper *[A Maximum Likelihood Oddity](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2682867?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)* by E.H. Oliver which is probably the primary source for the problem.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I appreciate you taking the time to find this. I think I see how I can use this to solve my problem. I will edit my post after reviewing this.

Comment: The link you provided says that the MLE must be one of the observations and so then the MLE bust be the largest value. Since, for example, if $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=4.5$ it couldn't possibly be the case that we observe a $10$. Hence, $\hat{\theta}_{MLE}=10$. Is that valid?

Comment: If you read carefully the paper by E.H. Oliver, the parameter $\theta$ does not have the same meaning as the upper bound $A$ is fixed (and hence differs from $2\theta$).

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/371207/